# What modern alternatives are there to C++ interface ideas by Dave Abrahams and Chris Diggins

Tags: c++, c++11, interface, architecture, implementation

I recently inherited a legacy simulation framework at my company which was written in the early 2000s as the main author was transitioning from C & Fortran to C++.  The interface/implementation architecture follows the ideas by Dave Abrahams and Chris Diggins from these 2 places:

1. http://groups.google.com/group/comp.std.c++/msg/85af30a61bf677e4
2. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8896/Polymorphism-without-Planning-under-the-hood

> This article explains the techniques used to allow the interface
>   reference types to be polymorphic on any type which provides matching
>   function signatures.
>   **Introduction**
>   My previous article, Polymorphism
>   without Planning, discussed how the OOTL (Object Oriented Template
>   Library) uses a technique implemented by the BIL (Boost Interfaces
>   Library) which is included with the OOTL release version 0.1. This
>   left a lot of people curious about what was going on under the hood.
>
> **Background**
>   The BIL allows any object that implements a set of
>   functions which match those of a declared interface, to be referred to
>   using a single type:
>
> ```
> class Dog {   
> public:
>     const char* MakeSound() { return "woof"; } 
> };
>
> class Duck {   
> public:
>     const char* MakeSound() { return "quack"; }
> };
>
> BOOST_IDL_BEGIN(IAnimal)
> BOOST_IDL_FXN0(MakeSound, const char*)
> BOOST_IDL_END(IAnimal)
>
> int main() {   
>     Dog dog;   
>     Duck duck;   
>     IAnimal animal = dog;  
>     puts(animal.MakeSound()); // prints woof   
>     animal = duck;  
>     puts(animal.MakeSound()); // prints quack   
>     return 0; 
> };
> ```
>
> The question
>   that I am asked frequently, is how in fact can we have statically
>   typed interfaces in C++, without placing any extra information in the
>   object?
>
> **Double-Width Pointers**
>   In order to achieve any kind of dynamic
>   dispatch, we require a function table lookup somewhere in our code,
>   otherwise we wouldn't be able to have run-time polymorphism. The
>   interface reference is then represented internally as a double width
>   pointer; one pointer points to the object, while the other object
>   points to a function table. This function table is created statically
>   at compile-time using templates.
>
> A function table is created for every class-to-interface type-cast in
>   the code. This is done using template versions of the assignment
>   operator and initializing constructor.
>
> **Creating Interfaces Reference Types by Hand**
>   Dave Abrahams of Boost-Consulting.com posted the following code to 
>   comp.std.c++ on 2004-04-25 which was an improvement on my original
>   proposal, and the technique used by the interface code generating tool
>   HeronFront.
>
> ```
> // a baz "interface" 
> class baz {  
> private:
> // forward declarations
>     template <class T>
>     struct functions;
>
>  public:
>     // interface
>     template <class T>
>     baz(T& x) : _m_a(&x), _m_t(&functions<T>::table)
>     {}
>
> int foo(int x)
> { return _m_t->foo(const_cast<void*>(_m_a), x); }
>
> int bar(char const* x)
> { return _m_t->bar(const_cast<void*>(_m_a), x); }
>
> private:
> // Function table type for the baz interface
> struct table_type
> {
>     int (*foo)(void*, int x);
>     int (*bar)(void*, char const*);
> };
>
> // For a given referenced type T, generates functions for the
> // function table and a static instance of the table.
> template <class T>
> struct functions
> {
>     static baz::table_type const table;
>
>     static int foo(void* p, int x)
>     { return static_cast<T*>(p)->foo(x); }
>
>     static int bar(void* p, char const* x)
>     { return static_cast<T*>(p)->bar(x); }
> };
>
> void const* _m_a;
> table const* _m_t; };
>
> template <class T> baz::table_type const baz::functions<T>::table = 
>     {
>          &baz::functions<T>::foo   , &baz::functions<T>::bar 
>     };
>
> struct some_baz {
>     int foo(int x) { return x + 1; }
>     int bar(char const* s) { return std::strlen(s); } 
> };
>
> struct another_baz {
>     int foo(int x) { return x - 1; }
>     int bar(char const* s) { return -std::strlen(s); } 
> };
>
> int main() {
>     some_baz f;
>     another_baz f2;
>     baz p = f; 
>     std::printf("p.foo(3) = %d\n", p.foo(3));
>     std::printf("p.bar('hi') = %d\n", p.bar("hi"));
>     p = f2;
>     std::printf("p.foo(3) = %d\n", p.foo(3));
>     std::printf("p.bar('hi') = %d\n", p.bar("hi")); 
> }
> ```
>
> **About the Code**
>   The above code defines an interface reference named `baz` manually,
>   which can refer to any type which provides functions matching the
>   function pointers in the `baz::table`.
>
> Every interface reference variable stores a pointer to its function
>   table through the variable `baz::_m_t` and stores a pointer to the
>   object in `baz::_m_a`.
>
> What the code does is generate a static function table for every class
>   `T` that is passed to a `baz`. These static function tables have type
>   `baz::table_type` and are named `baz::function<T>::table`. Even though
>   there is only one name, because it is a static template variable of
>   `baz::function`, there is a separate one created for every instance of
>   `baz::function`. To put it another way, we use the compiler to generate
>   a function table for every class - interface pair possibility at
>   compile-time.
>
> **Summary** 
>   The technique described, even though it is sophisticated, is
>   still a simplification of how the BIL is implemented. The BIL is
>   considerably more complex because it also provides support for a wide
>   range of techniques such as Aspect Oriented Programming, Delegations,
>   Generic Programming, and more. The BIL is also required to work around
>   certain limitations of the C++ pre-processor. I will write more in the
>   future about the BIL as it matures, and is released officially into
>   the public domain. Hopefully, this article does help explain the
>   theory behind the technique and can provide you with some insight into
>   the interface reference types.

The architecture of the framework has served us very well over the years, but as we finally have all the security paperwork to use more modern compilers than those included with Red Hat by default, I would like to start upgrading the framework to use modern C++.

Does anyone have a better way to design a Interface/Implementation architecture which supports dynamic polymorphism?

Comment: Unfortunately, the article that link #2 is based on doesn't exist anymore, and doesn't even appear in the Wayback Machine. However, the original article appears to also exist at this link: https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=81901

Comment: links die, please add a [mre] to your question which doesn't rely on external sites

Comment: @Spencer: The linked article includes a fair amount that I don't see where you've linked, so I've added it to the question.

Comment: Sadly, I'm confused. Isn't this just reinventing the wheel? Yes, before C++ there were a number of poly models and implementations, and some code did need to be coerced from C, obective C, etc to work under c++, and many of those just treat c++ as C on steroids. But you guys have had 10 years almost to work out how to do what you want using built-in c++11 standardised virtualisation, surely?

Comment: That's because the article you linked to is the sequel of the one I linked to.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is what you want:

```
// a baz "interface" 
class baz {  
private:
    struct IWrapper
    {
        virtual ~IWrapper() = default;
        virtual int foo(int) = 0;
        virtual int bar(const char*) = 0;
    };

    template <typename T>
    struct Wrapper : IWrapper
    {
        T& t;

        Wrapper(T& t) : t(t) {}
        int foo(int n) override { return t.foo(n); }
        int bar(const char* s) override { return t.bar(s); }
    };

    std::unique_ptr<IWrapper> wrapper;

 public:
    // interface
    template <class T>
    baz(T& x) : wrapper(std::make_unique<Wrapper<T>>(x)) {}

    int foo(int x) { return wrapper->foo(x); }
    int bar(char const* x) { return wrapper->bar(x); }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cf751285310b4f52)

- memory allocation might be avoid we placement new.
- `baz::foo`/`baz::bar` might be omitted with `operator->` but change syntax of caller.
- copy is disabled here, shared_ptr or adding clone method might solve issue.

All that doesn't really require C++11 or more though (except smart pointer)

Comment: Yeah, I remember seeing this in "c++ seasoning" by Sean Parent in 2013 - it's a good one - but this what confuses me as well about the question - you don't really need any c++11/14/17 features to pull this off.

Answer (score 1):

### Template constructor + std::function

The following uses a templated constructor and a `std::function` to bind the call. It hardly gets any simpler than this. Perhaps it's a bit more verbose than the MACRO solution but not by much. The real trick is just the templated constructor and std::function as public member. `std::bind` could have been used instead of the lambda.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

class Dog {   
public:
    const char* MakeSound() { return "woof"; } 
};

class Duck {   
public:
    const char* MakeSound() { return "quack"; }
};

struct IAnimal {
  template<class T>
  IAnimal(T& t) : MakeSound{ [&t]{return t.MakeSound();}}
  {}

  std::function<const char*()> MakeSound;
};

int main() {   
    Dog dog;   
    Duck duck;   
    IAnimal animal = dog;  
    std::cout << animal.MakeSound() << std::endl; // prints woof   
    animal = duck;  
    std::cout << animal.MakeSound() << std::endl; // prints quack   
    return 0; 
};
```

[Link to godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/KnEzSc)